# Python dic replacement is not working

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

For multiple string replacement, I've the code,

```
import ast
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text 

my_text = open('p.txt', 'r').read()
reps2 = open('dic.txt', 'r').read()
reps3 = ast.literal_eval(reps2)  
txt = replace_all(my_text, reps3)
print txt
```

However, only few key to value conversion takes place. I'm newbie in python and please suggest where is the problem. dic.txt has 30000 key value pairs.

p.txt file content is like,

```
OS11T0116000
OS01T0331100

OS11T0116000
OS03T0663800

OS11T0116000
OS05T0189904

OS11T0116000
OS08T0528500
```

And the dic.txt file content is like,

```
{'Os01T0101800':'LOC_Os01g01170',
 'Os01T0101900':'LOC_Os01g01180',
 'Os01T0102000':'LOC_Os01g01190',
 'Os01T0102300':'LOC_Os01g01280',
 'Os01T0102400':'LOC_Os01g01290',
 'Os01T0102500':'LOC_Os01g01295'}
```

Comment: This isn’t your problem here, but you should not be just writing `str(dic)` to a file and using `literal_eval` to read or back. Use a format designed for persistence. If your file is just a dictionary mapping strings to strings, `json.dump`/`json.load` is great for that. (Or even a dbm.)

Comment: In your example, no key from the dictionary matches any line in the text, even after the case conversion. I suggest that you add a more realistic example.

Comment: Use i.upper() in replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original text is in the upper case, but the `'s'`s in the dictionary are in the lower case. `'S'` and `'s'` are two different letters. Add the upper-case versions of the keys to the dictionary:

```
reps3.update({k.upper(): v for k, v in reps3.items()})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DYZ. After hours of testing, I couldn't find that case sensitive problem. Yes, I should have added a working example, my mistake.